# Twoway binding causes strange behaviour in maps control for wp7

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-phone-7, mvvm, bing-maps

I'm developing an application for windows phone using the maps control. The map control binds its center and its zoomlevel property to two properties on a viewmodel.

The map control is on a page seperate from the mainpage of the application. Every time a user moves to the map the page binds to a viewmodel. This viewmodel is a singleton (always the same instance).

the first time I move to the map navigating on the map works fine, but when I go back and navigate to the map again, navigation has some sort of bounce like it is push backed to its initial location.
To see this behaviour do the following:

- Navigate to the mapPage bij clicking on the button on the mainpage. At this time the map control works as expected.
- Click the back button to return to the mainpage.
- Click the button on the mainpage again to navigate to the mappage for the second time. Now when sliding the map the control behaves strange by bouncing back to the original location before sliding.

The mainpage contains just a button to navigate to the map page which looks as follows:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="MapTester.Map"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
    DataContext="{Binding Path=MapViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <maps:Map Center="{Binding Center, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ZoomLevel="{Binding ZoomLevel,Mode=TwoWay}"
                  ZoomBarVisibility="Visible"
                  CredentialsProvider=""
                  ScaleVisibility="Visible"></maps:Map>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

The MapViewModel is defined on the ViewModelLocator. I created a solution to demonstrate then problem. You can download it here https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=25374d9051083633&sc=documents&id=25374D9051083633%21344#

Does anybody have an idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem too, have you found the solution for it JLaanstra?

Comment: So what I believe I did is remove the bindings when navigating away.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what's wrong here? Unless you're navigating backwards (and thus not setting the DataContext), Bing Maps will always do a "bounce" animation from global view to the center location. This is how the control work, so nothing you can do about that.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear on how to reproduce this behaviour. I updated my initial post with steps on how to reproduce the strange behaviour.